# pandas lambda tuple mapping

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to compute a range (confidence interval) to return two values in lambda mapped over a column.

```
M=12.4; n=10; T=1.3
dt =  pd.DataFrame( { 'vc' : np.random.randn(10) } )    
ci = lambda c : M + np.asarray( -c*T/np.sqrt(n) , c*T/np.sqrt(n) )
dt['ci'] = dt['vc'].map( ci )
print '\n confidence interval ', dt['ci'][:,1]
```

..er , so how does this get done?

then, how to unpack the tuple in a lambda? 
(I want to check if the range >0, ie contains the mean)
**neither of the following work:**

```
appnd = lambda c2: c2[0]*c2[1] > 0 and 1 or 0
app2 = lambda x,y: x*y >0 and 1 or 0
dt[cnt] = dt['ci'].map(app2)
```

Comment: `T` is not defined in your example, and lines 4 + 5 also throw errors (`dt['vc']`, Indexing).

Comment: sorry, T is just the t-statistic.. (its just a toy example, the real problem is getting a tuple out/in to lambda/map

Comment: again my apologies, I simplified it from my real example (where I am passing variable names for a set of columns, etc.)... Ive added the quotes and created a value for T...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably easier to see by defining a proper function for the CI, rather than a `lambda`.

As far as the unpacking goes, maybe you could let the function take an argument for whether to add or subtract, and then apply it twice.

You should also calculate the mean and size in the function, instead of assigning them ahead of time.

```
In [40]: def ci(arr, op, t=2.0):
            M = arr.mean()
            n = len(arr)
            rhs = arr * t / np.sqrt(n)
            return np.array(op(M, rhs))
```

You can import the `add` and `sub` functions from `operator`

From there it's just a one liner:

```
In [47]: pd.concat([dt.apply(ci, axis=1, op=x) for x in [sub, add]], axis=1)
Out[47]: 
         vc        vc
0 -0.374189  1.122568
1  0.217528 -0.652584
2 -0.636278  1.908835
3 -1.132730  3.398191
4  0.945839 -2.837518
5 -0.053275  0.159826
6 -0.031626  0.094879
7  0.931007 -2.793022
8 -1.016031  3.048093
9  0.051007 -0.153022

[10 rows x 2 columns]
```

I'd recommend breaking that into a few steps for clarity.
Get the minus one with `r1 = dt.apply(ci, axis=1, op=sub)`, and the plus with `r2 = dt.apply(ci, axis=1, op=add)`. Combine with `pd.concat([r1, r2], axis=1)`

Basically, it's hard to tell from `dt.apply` what the output should look like, just seeing some tuples. By applying separately, we get two 10 x 1 arrays.

Comment: Also, the posted lambda in the question doesn't actually return a tuple so there's nothing to unpack.  I think the transparency and clarity to breaking it up like Tom showed is the way to go.

Comment: thanks! took me a little bit to see the ox! would not have thought of that! thanks!